# Call from one web api to another web api within ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

In my **ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API (on .NET Core)** I want to call functions from **another ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web API (on .NET Framework)**.

I can do this manually by calling the http address of the functions. But are there any tools, which generates me the classes of the other web api for better using?

Comment: I don't know any tools for Web API, but You could write Your own proxy class.

Comment: What class should be generated?

Comment: Classes which I can use to post as model or get from a api function..

Answer (score 0):

I found out: The tool I need calls AutoRest: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score -1):

There is one great tool, you can generate C# classes from JSON or url, if that is what you want.

[**JSON Utils**](https://jsonutils.com/)

Comment: Visual Studio can do this for you automatically there is no need for an extra utility

Comment: If you mean on `Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as class` you need to install **Web Essentials**. Also you can't generate classes from URL, you need to paste JSON.
And in this tool you have some advanced settings like, PascalCase naming.
So it can be done with VS, but you can't tell that this is not useful library.
@AndreiDragotoniu